# How to define $\arcsin(\sin\theta)$ on picewise sub-intervals?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

We know that $\sin: [-\pi/2,\pi/2]\to [-1,1]$ is invertible and $\arcsin: [-1,1]\to  [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.
But I want to define $\arcsin(\sin\theta)$.

If $\theta\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$, i.e., $\pi/2\leq \theta\leq 3\pi/2$, then
  $-\pi/2\leq \theta-\pi\leq \pi/2$ and so
  $\arcsin(\sin\theta)=\theta-\pi$.

Again, if   $\theta\in[(2n-1)\pi/2,(2n+1)\pi/2]$ for  $n\in\mathbf{Z}$, then

$-\pi/2\leq \theta-n\pi\leq \pi/2$  and so

$\arcsin(\sin\theta)=\theta-n\pi$ for all integers $n$.

I don't know whether my approach is true or not.

Answer (score 0):

Prelude

$\arcsin(\theta)$ is not the inverse of $\sin(\theta)$, but rather 
it's the inverse of $\sin(\theta)$ restricted to the domain $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Thus, restricted $\sin\theta$ has

domain = $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$

range = $[-1,1]$

and its inverse, $\arcsin(\theta)$ has

domain = $[-1,1]$

range = $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$

when $\sin\theta$ is used in an expression such
as $\arcsin(\sin(\theta))$, the $\sin\theta$ part is ordinary $\sin$,
not restricted $\sin$. The composition is well defined
since the range of $\sin(\theta)$ is contained in the domain
of $\arcsin(\theta)$.

FInally, let me remark that the functions

$$\sin(\arcsin\theta)$$

and

$$\arcsin(\sin\theta)$$

Are completely different.

The function $\sin(\arcsin(\theta))$ has

domain = $[-1,1]$

range = $[-1,1]$

and is identically equal to $\theta$ on its domain, hence its
graph is the portion of the graph $y = \theta$ for $-1 \leq \theta \leq 1$.

The function $\arcsin(\sin(\theta))$ has

domain = $[-\infty,\infty]$

range = $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$

and is a continuous, piecewise-linear with period $2\pi$ 
whose graph has a "saw-tooth" shape.

Really last final remark:

while its correct to simplify the expression

$\sin(\arcsin(\theta))$ to $\theta$

for all $\theta$ for which it's defined (that is $-1 \leq \theta \leq 1$),
it's incorrect (and is a common student error) to 
simplify

$\arcsin(\sin(\theta))$ to $\theta$

unless it is known that $-\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$

Comment: @FT, you have told that  $\arcsin(x)$ and $\sin^{-1}(x)$ are different. What is the difference between these?

Comment: @user356595 Please, read better what I wrote. I never said that.

Comment: If the real line is partitioned in subintervals, what will give $\arcsin(\sin\theta)$ on that subinterval?

Comment: @FT, $\sin(\theta)$ is invertible on each of the subintervals  $[(2n-1)\pi/2,(2n+1)\pi/2]$ for  $n\in\mathbf{Z}$, so I want to know if $\theta\in[(2n-1)\pi/2,(2n+1)\pi/2]$ for  $n\in\mathbf{Z}$, then what will be $\arcsin(sin\theta)$?